# Why doesn't IIS release files on the server?

Tags: asp.net, file, iis

I have ASP.NET Web Forms application for fill e-warranty pdf. When I open file for first time and fill filds everything is OK. But if I want to open file again and fill it, throw me exception on `File.WriteAllBytes(pdfDirectory, pdfContent);`:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '...\AllWarranties\2016\2\000101.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

If I open another file, make changes on them, and return to first one then dont'throw me exception.

Why doesn't IIS release files on the server? On local machine works perfect.

**Code**

```
string pdfDirectory = @"C:\Projects\Amco\EWarranty\EWarranty" + currentFilePath.FilePath;
MemoryStream inputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(pdfDirectory))
{
    inputMemoryStream.SetLength(fs.Length);
    fs.Read(inputMemoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fs.Length);
    inputMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputMemoryStream);
using (Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Projects\Amco\EWarranty\pechatAMCO.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream))
    {
        if (currentServiceMap.FailureNumber == 0)
        {
            var pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(3);
            Image image = Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
            image.ScaleToFit(150, 150);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(140, 425);
            pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
        }

        // Some other else if statements ...

        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        BaseFont cyrillicFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        pdfFormFields.AddSubstitutionFont(cyrillicFont);

        // first fail
        if (txt_First_Adoption_Date.Text != "")
        {
            pdfFormFields.SetField("firstAdoptionDate", txt_First_Adoption_Date.Text);
        }

        if (txt_First_Failure.Text != "")
        {
            pdfFormFields.SetField("firstFailure", txt_First_Failure.Text);
        }

        if (txt_First_Return_Date.Text != "")
        {
            pdfFormFields.SetField("firstReturnDate", txt_First_Return_Date.Text);
        }

        // Second, third and so on failds ...

            warrantyService.UpdateServiceMapByAdmin(CurrentSessions.warrantyNumber, txt_First_Adoption_Date.Text, txt_First_Failure.Text, "", txt_First_Return_Date.Text, txt_Second_Adoption_Date.Text, txt_Second_Failure.Text,
                                                        "", txt_Second_Return_Date.Text, txt_Third_Adoption_Date.Text, txt_Third_Failure.Text, "", txt_Third_Return_Date.Text, txt_Fourth_Adoption_Date.Text, txt_Fourth_Failure.Text,
                                                        "", txt_Fourth_Return_Date.Text, txt_Fifth_Adoption_Date.Text, txt_Fifth_Failure.Text, "", txt_Fifth_Return_Date.Text, (currentServiceMap.FailureNumber + 1));

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
    }

    byte[] pdfContent = outputStream.ToArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(pdfDirectory, pdfContent);
}

pdfReader.Close();
inputMemoryStream.Close();
```