# What is meant by application is hosted within w3wp.exe (In-process) or application.exe/dotnet.exe(outofprocess) in hosting terms

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel, w3wp

For example, AppDomain is a logical container and for security and separation (sandboxing), an application runs within an AppDomain. Here I can understand the term "within" (something inside).

But what does it mean when we say the app is hosted within w3wp.exe, is it a boundary? Or, the application really executes within this exe, magically?

If it was stated as the application runs by w3wp.exe then I could digest it.

I am really new to the programming world so, I am asking this, please don't be rude.

Comment: You should find the diagrams easy to understand, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0 Spend no more time on `AppDomain` as .NET Core no longer allows multiple `AppDomain` in a single process.

Comment: @Lex Li, No, it doesn't answer, i am asking what is meant by the word within? does w3wp executes app inside it by creating some kind of boundry?

Comment: w3wp.exe is an instance which created by application pool. [This document](https://stackify.com/w3wp-exe-iis-worker-process/) may help with your question. You can also refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822898/what-is-w3wp-exe) about this question.